# NextPrime[2^n] = NextPrime[3^m] has infinite groups of positive integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have a conjecture on next prime:

Conjecture (**NextPrime Conjecture**): Integer equation `NextPrime[2^n] = NextPrime[3^m]` on $m,n$ has infinite groups of positive integer solutions. When $2$ and $3$ are replaced by other two primes, it is also true!

```
In[59]:= t2 = Table[NextPrime[2^n], {n, 1, 200}];
t3 = Table[NextPrime[3^m], {m, 1, 190}];
t2 \[Intersection] t3


Out[59]= {5, 11}
```

My questions are:

1. Do you think the NextPrime Conjecture is TRUE or FALSE?
2. What is the third solution of `NextPrime[2^n] = NextPrime[3^m]`, except `5==NextPrime[2^2]==NextPrime[3]` and `11==NextPrime[2^3]==NextPrime[3^2]`?

Comment: Do you have any specific reason to believe that this might be true? Do you have any ideas about how you might prove it? What makes this more than an idea restated as a conjecture?

Comment: @Mark Bennet  no specific reason, no idea to prove . I think this question is as hard as Riemann hypothesis

Answer (score 2):

According to the (unproven) [Redmond-Sun conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redmond%E2%80%93Sun_conjecture), your conjecture is false. Indeed, for $n,m>1$ your condition is equivalent to there being no prime strictly between $2^n$ and $3^m$. Redmond-Sun conjecture states that a gap between two powers doesn't contain a prime only finitely many times.

If you believe that the list provided on Wikipedia is complete, then there isn't even the third number satisfying your condition.

Comment: Yes，NextPrime Conjecture is fighting with Redmond-Sun conjecture,   But, at whose hand will the deer die? I can't accept a reference for answer. In my opinion, Redmond-Sun conjecture is FALSE, which only verified below 10^12.

Comment: @aboy From what you have said in question body, you have even less evidence for your own conjecture. Checking numbers up to exponent $200$ and finding only two examples isn't a good evidence for infinitude.

Comment: @aboy By the way, according to [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A116086), there are no solutions up to $4.5\cdot 10^{18}$.

Comment: no solutions up to 10^88 ---- the total of cosmos atoms, I believe! but I still insist my NextPrime Conjecture

Comment: @aboy Right now I'm asking out of pure curiosity, but do you have any reason to insist that NextPrime conjecture should be true?

Comment: It's relatively easy to disprove the "NextPrime Conjecture", using standard lower bounds for $|3^x-2^y|$ from linear forms in logarithms (as in de Weger's thesis) and upper bounds for gaps between primes.

Comment: @MikeBennett If you have a complete proof of that, you should definitely give it as an answer to this question.

Comment: @ Mike Bennett, Not so obvious! I still insist  the NextPrime Conjecture, after looked https://books.google.com/books?id=1BnoBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA397&lpg=PA397&dq=de+Weger%27s+thesis&source=bl&ots=zNOxqmlo3H&sig=i4Bu1UCYcUOPtKOxXt53GUht3gk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6-4f86LTJAhVFWhoKHXXdAyAQ6AEIUjAJ#v=onepage&q=de%20Weger's%20thesis&f=false   page397

Comment: @aboy - insisting is irrelevant. Proof or at least convincing numerical evidence.

Answer (score 1):

We have $|2^x - 3^y| > 2^x e^{-\frac{x}{10}} > 2^x4^{-\frac{x}{10}} = 2^{\frac{4}{5}x}$ for x > 27
(See the link you posted in a comment. [Unsolved Problems in Number Theory](https://books.google.de/books?id=1BnoBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA397&lpg=PA397&dq=de%20Weger%27s%20thesis&source=bl&ots=zNOxqmlo3H&sig=i4Bu1UCYcUOPtKOxXt53GUht3gk&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=de%20Weger%27s%20thesis&f=false))

As an upper bound for prime gaps we have $g_n < p_n^\theta$ where $\theta = \frac{3}{4} + \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ for n big enough. (See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds))

If n is big enough, we have for prime gaps near $2^x$: $g_n$ < $2^{x(\frac{3}{4} + \epsilon)}$. So if we take $\epsilon$ small enough and n big enough, the prime gap is smaller then the difference of powers of 2 and 3.

I didn't formulate it 100% rigorous. But I think the idea should be clear.